# WebDriverIO - handling Prompt Sign In messages

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver-io

I've been at this for awhile but wasn't able to find any solution through documentations.

Essentially I am testing in an QA environment that requires password credentials.

Although I can manually type the username/password, ideally I'd like to have it automated in my test.

Is this possible through WebdriverIO?

[image]

Comment: If that's a basic auth sign in, you can do it by putting the credentials in the URL, and it looks from e.g. https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio/issues/837 like that's all that's supported.

Comment: awesome, that did the trick!

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above, simply add the credentials in the url (with your own `userName` and `passWord`:

```
const credentials = `https://userName:passWord@`
const URLEnv = 'www.google.com'
const url = credentials + URLEnv

....

describe('Google page', () => {
    it('should have the right title', () => {
        browser.url(url);
        const title = browser.getTitle();
        const correctResult = 'Google'
        expect(title).toEqual(correctResult);
    });
});
```